# R: Set up and choose values based on labels

Tags: r, dataframe, shiny

I have some function I want to run on data, and the data selected depends on user selection (Shiny).
For example, consider this:

dumb_input = any of following values ("english", "spanish", "french", "german")

So, I'm hoping to access different data based on the language choice. What is the best way to set this up? I have the code below using a DataFrame, but I think it's probably way inefficient:

```
#objective: get the name 'arthur' when 'english' is selected
langs = c("english", "spanish", "french", "german")
names = c("arthur", "pablo", "antoine", "hans")
data_names = data.frame(langs, names, stringsasfactors = FALSE)

data_names[data_names[1]==dumb_input,] <--- this obviously is still a dataframe giving us ["english", "arthur"] so we go further
as.character(data_names[data_names[1]==dumb_input,][2]) #returns "arthur"
```

So, is there any better way to do this? I feel like there must be. Can this be done with another R structure also, such as a list?

Comment: also, i'm wondering if the "as.character()" function in the last line of my code is necessary.

Comment: i thiink you need `data_names[[1]]`

Comment: @akrun can you be more specific? data_names[[1]] just gives me the langs vector

Comment: I guess at a time you are providding a single element and you want to `filter` the rows basedd on that?  Then `==` is fine.  If you wanted to split up the data, then just do `split(data_names, data_names$langs)`

Answer (score 1):

If you just want `names` based on `dumb_input`, you could use `match`.

```
dumb_input <- 'french'
data_names$names[match(dumb_input, data_names$langs)]
#[1] "antoine"
```

Or with `==`

```
data_names$names[data_names$langs == dumb_input]
```

---

Remember R is case-sensitive, while constructing the dataframe you probably meant to use :

```
data_names = data.frame(langs, names, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found that the *hash* library works OK on this:

```
#objective: get the name 'arthur' when 'english' is selected
langs = c("english", "spanish", "french", "german")
names = c("arthur", "pablo", "antoine", "hans")
data_names_hash = hash (keys = langs, values = names)

data_names_hash[["german"]] 
#[1] hans
```